Movie I saw on TV with childhood memories of killing a fish with a stick, later rebuilding life
I saw a movie on TV a long ago and I can not remember at all what it was called. Here are some details:

I think it's a drama from 1990-2012  
Brutally killed a fish with a stick with a nail on it on a lake with his friend brutally (childhood memory)  
Talks to a psychologist or cop (female) about his problems (in present)  
Makes new friends, spend the club saves his friends from some thugs foot hitting those who have joined together on the roof happening events  
Trying to rebuild his life after tragic events (i guess) 

The date that I have given may not accurate, but it's just what I remember.

Just to be clear, are these sentences "Kill a fish with a stick nail ...", "Talk to a psychologist / cop ..." and the rest describing scenes in the movie?

These are events that I remember. I saw the movie in two or three years ago. I do not know if they are true or not.You can give me some examples to compare them.

@Pain for future reference, to separate lines, like in the list you tried to make above, put 2 spaces at the end of each line.

I tried to clean up the grammar a bit. Somewhat stumped by the 4th bullet, though. I can't make heads or tails out of that one.

"what's his name", you've set a gender to the movie. Kool. :)

sorry for my google translate english :))

I'm sort of sure that you're looking for this one Boy A.
Plot:

The story of a young ex-con Jack, newly released from serving a prison
  sentence for a murder he committed as a child.

The scene you described,

Brutally killed a fish with a stick with a nail on it on a lake with
  his friend brutally (childhood memory)

Yes, it's his childhood memory, he does it with his friend at the lake.
More description about the movie from wiki.

Eric Wilson befriends Philip Craig, who is a troublemaker and rescues
  him from a group of bullies. It is later disclosed that Philip is the
  victim of rape perpetrated by his older brother. Philip gets into an
  argument with a girl from their school who comes across the two boys
  loitering in a park. She criticizes them and refers to them as "scum"
  when she witnesses Philip vandalising a park sign with a Stanley
  knife. Philip approaches her and starts slashing at her forearms with
  the knife. He grabs the girl and drags her under a bridge. When Philip
  drops the knife, Eric picks it up, and follows them under the bridge.
  The girl is killed, although the film shows neither who kills her nor
  how.
Eric (dubbed as Boy A during the trial) and Philip are remanded into
  custody at secure units. Philip ends up dead, assumed to be suicide,
  but Eric believes that he may have been killed by youth offenders.
  Eric is later released and is guided by rehabilitation worker Terry
  (Peter Mullan). Eric, shy and eager to be a good citizen again, builds
  up a new life under the name Jack Burridge. He finds a job, befriends
  his colleague Chris (Shaun Evans), falls in love with the office girl,
  Michelle (Katie Lyons), and rescues a little girl who would otherwise
  have died after a car crash. An article in a local newspaper portrays
  him as a hero and includes a picture of both boys in the story. Eric
  wants to be honest with Michelle and reveal his past, but Terry urges
  him not to do so because it is too dangerous. Terry is afraid that
  people may attack Eric because there is a reward of £20,000 for
  finding him. Terry argues that it is not dishonest because "Eric is
  history and Jack is a new person".

It's a Drama and here's the trailer.




This is the movie.Thanks a lot!

@Pain you're welcome.
